# PHp open popup window when website is open but only first time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have one requirement to open popup message box when user open website but it should be open first time only. Suppose user close window and open   website again then it should be display again.How it is possible? any script ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29986657/global-variable-usage-on-page-reload/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [setcookie](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) to store a **non-persistent** cookie to remember if you've shown the popup message previously.

To set a non-persistent cookie, you simply leave the expiration time empty or set it to 0.

> If set to 0, or omitted, the cookie will expire at the end of the session (when the browser closes).

You can add it like this:

```
setcookie('seen_popup', true);
```

Then check if the user has seen it previously:

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE['seen_popup'])):
    // print your popup..
    <div id="popup">
         My message
    </div>
endif;
```

And in jQuery, check if the popup exists before showing it:

```
if($('#popup').length){
    // execute code
}
```